# wipe multiple disks at the same time?

Tags: disk-management

is there an app that can do this? Trying to simulate dban without actually using dban.

I know I can dd but is it safe to run dd on multiple instances of the terminal? Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of "at the same time"? Both answers are using a sequential method; that is not "at the same time".

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what is your favourite way of formatting disks, I would go with `mkfs`. The following method/trick will work with other commands as well:

You can use GNU `parallel`.

Suppose you would like to format

```
/dev/sda1 which is ext4 partition,
/dev/sda2 which is ntfs partition,
/dev/sdb5 which is etx3 partition,
/dev/sdf1 which is ext4 partition
```

You can create a text file (say `input.txt`) with commandline options for `mkfs`, e.g.:

```
-t ext4 /dev/sda1
-t ntfs /dev/sda2
-t ext3 /dev/sdb5
-t ext4 /dev/sdf1
```

Then run

```
parallel -a input.txt mkfs
```

If you would like to pass different parameters to an individual partition (e.g. partition label or other options), you can add them to the corresponding line.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to run multiple instances of dd wiping different devices. You could also get a speed up in total time needed to wipe different devices.
If wiping on single device, but like two partitions - then run dd for one then another.